# send an additional email to customer to inform we are delivering the product in magento

Tags: email, delivery

send additional emails to customers through magento admin panel.

as in default magento , we have an option for sending mails when customer ordered the product.

and when we click invoice  and shipment and credit memo button.

we want to send a mail to customer to inform we are delivering the product.

is there any option to do that through automatic way?

Comment: Does something like this help 
http://www.atwix.com/magento/emails-for-custom-events/
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8793824/programmaticly-send-email-when-shipping-tracking-number-is-set
I used this before but also with the cancelation, in your case you would just have to set the event to shipped and then send a transactional email

Comment: With delivery do you mean deliver yourself, like with pizza?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you deliver product, you create Shipment document in Magento.

In the form which allows you to create Shipment there is "Email Copy of Shipment" checkbox. Select that checkbox before using "Submit Shipment" button and Magento should send email notification to customer.

Optionally you can fill "Shipment Comments" field and you can include that in email by clicking on "Append Comments" checkbox.

Comment: i will check your solution and tell you soon....